# Regex for text files with partially incomplete nested structure

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to parse a file with this nested format:

```
/begin FUNCTION

    foo
    "1.2.12 foo_long"

    /begin DEF1
    /end DEF1
    FUNCTION_VERSION "1.2.0"

/end FUNCTION

/begin FUNCTION

    bar
    ""

/end FUNCTION

/begin FUNCTION

    urbi
    "10.15.23 urbi_long"

    /begin DEF1
    /end DEF1
    FUNCTION_VERSION "10.15.3"

/end FUNCTION
```

From this I want to extract the function names, the longnames and the version number.

I do this with the following regex:

```
sSearch = r'/begin FUNCTION\s+(\w*)\s+"[\d\._\s]*([^"]+)*"(.*?)FUNCTION_VERSION\s+"([^"]+)"\s+/end FUNCTION'
lMatches = re.findall(sSearch, sFileContent, re.S)
dMatches = {args[0]: [args[3], args[1]] for args in lMatches if args}
print(dMatches)
```

This leads to:

```
{'foo': ['1.2.0', 'foo_long'], 'bar': ['10.15.3', '']}
```

The function version from `urbi` is wrongly assigned to `bar`. I do not want `bar` returned at all as it does not contain a function version.

How can I adapt the regex that it releases the `/begin FUNCTION` occurance before `bar` when `end FUNCTION` is found without a leading `function version`?

I would want the output to be:

```
{'foo': ['1.2.0', 'foo_long'], 'urbi': ['10.15.3', 'urbi_long']}
```

P.S. What I also find confusing is why I need to add an unnecessary `(.*?)` capturing group in the middle. Should it not also work with a simple `.*`?

Comment: It would be better if you post the desired outputs too

Comment: @Gurman: You are right, I have added the desired output.

Comment: Is [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/o8rshs/1) what you wanted?

Comment: @Gurman: That does not look too bad, but I want the version number from the field `FUNCTION_VERSION` not from the text field as the information in the text field could be not correct.

Comment: @anubhava: You are right. I have not generalized the example to remove the ambiguity in my question.

Comment: @Gurman: No. That is exactly what I had. `bar` is returned instead of `urbi`.

Comment: @mrCarnivore Final Answer :D [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/o8rshs/3)

Comment: @anubhava: Exactly.

Comment: @Gurman: Yes that looks good. Post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: [This should work for given input data](https://regex101.com/r/o8rshs/4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
\/begin FUNCTION\s*(\w+)\s*"(?:(?!end FUNCTION)[\s\S])*?(\w+)"[\s\S]*?FUNCTION_VERSION\s*"([^"\s]+)"
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o8rshs/3)**

**Explanation:**

- `\/begin FUNCTION\s*` - matches `/begin FUNCTION` followed by 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of word character and captures it in group 1. This is your function's name
- `\s*"` - matches 0+ whitespaces followed by a `"`
- `(?:(?!end FUNCTION)[\s\S])*?` - Tempered Greedy token that will match any character until it starts with the phrase `end FUNCTION`
- `(\w+)` - matches 1+ word characters and store it in group 2. This captures your long-name
- `"[\s\S]*?FUNCTION_VERSION\s*"` - matches `"` followed by 0+ occurrences of any character followed by `FUNCTION_VERSION` followed by 0+ whitespaces followed by `"`
- `([^"\s]+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is neither a `"` nor a whitespace. This is captured in group 3 and contains your version number.
- `"` - matches `"`

Comment: Strangely this breaks when the longname is in brackets: `"1.2.0 (foo_long)"`. Then it does not find the occurance any more and exhibits the same problem as in my question but in another place...

Comment: That is because the 2nd capture group only captured `\w+` which does not include parenthesis. If you change `(\w+)` to `([\w()]+)`, it should work.

Comment: Since I also want to enable German special characters I seem to have to change it to `?([^"]+)`. However, this does not strip the (maybe wrong) version number from the beginning of the text.

Comment: No.This still does not allow `()`.

Comment: Nevermind. My example contains multiple words for the longname that makes things even more complicated. However, I would ask a new question for this if I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mrCarnivore I have changed the regex a bit [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/o8rshs/6). It covers the parenthesis and also spaces /multiple words in long_names

Comment: Thank you that does indeed work nicely! However, I now realized again how very difficult it is to provide a minimal but complete example of my problem: our newest solution breaks when the function without `FUNCTION_VERSION`-tag does contain a non-empty longname field. So your newest solution is not very robust since it skips over the `/end FUNCTION` like in my original example...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a `negative lookahead` as follows:

```
import re

with open('filename.txt') as fd:
    data = fd.read()

regex = re.compile(
    r'begin\s+FUNCTION\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)\s+'
    r'(?:"[\d.]+\d\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)")?'
    r'(?:(?:(?!/end\s+FUNCTION).)+FUNCTION_VERSION\s+"([\d.]+\d)")?',
    re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL
)
result = {i[0]: [i[2], i[1]] for i in regex.findall(data)}
print(result)

#outpout
{'urbi': ['10.15.3', 'urbi_long'], 'foo': ['1.2.0', 'foo_long'], 'bar': ['', '']}

#refine result
result = {k: [i for i in v if i] for k, v in result.items()}
print(result)

# output
{'urbi': ['10.15.3', 'urbi_long'], 'foo': ['1.2.0', 'foo_long'], 'bar': []}
```

Comment: That is also an interesting solution. However, it also returns the first part of the longname string instead of the `FUNCTION_VERSION` field for the function version.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `Lookbehind & Lookahead`.

**Demo:**

```
import re

s = """/begin FUNCTION

    foo
    "1.2.0 foo_long"

    /begin DEF1
    /end DEF1
    FUNCTION_VERSION "1.2.0"

/end FUNCTION

/begin FUNCTION

    bar
    ""

/end FUNCTION

/begin FUNCTION

    urbi
    "10.15.3 urbi_long"

    /begin DEF1
    /end DEF1
    FUNCTION_VERSION "10.15.3"

/end FUNCTION"""

result = {}
for i in re.findall(r"(?<=/begin FUNCTION)(.*?)(?=/end FUNCTION)", s, flags=re.DOTALL):
    val = i.strip().splitlines()
    if val:
        try:
            result[val[0]] = val[1].replace('"', "").split()
        except:
            result[val[0]] = []
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'urbi': ['10.15.3', 'urbi_long'], 'foo': ['1.2.0', 'foo_long'], 'bar': []}
```

Comment: The Lookahead and Lookbehind looks good, but the information frmo the function version is not taken from the `function_version` field but from the longname textfield. Moreover, I do not feel confident with the very rigid and not content aware parsing after the regex. What happens when there is another tag after the function_version?